# How can I get more involved with the Ask Ubuntu community?

Tags: discussion, community

I have been an Ubuntu user for a while but recently found out how great the community is.

This has quickly become yet another reason I love Ubuntu and I would like to be more involved.

What else can I do, except answering questions and editing posts, to be a more productive member of this community?

Comment: Come to the [chat], the bottomless pit..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can hang out in chat and help out. I usually post sets of questions or queries that could use editing, that sort of thing.

Answer (score 7):

I don't know what exactly is meant by *more involved*. If you are answering questions and editing posts, I think you are involved already.

Here are some suggestions from me:

- Try to upvote great posts, both questions and answers.
- Try to find duplicate questions and flag the questions for moderator attention, so that they can be closed.
- Downvote wrong, dangerous answers which can create more harm.
- And finally, editing. Edit posts with bad formatting, incorrect tags. Editing is considered truly a great contribution to the community. You can visit the [review](http://meta.askubuntu.com/review/) section to see low-quality posts.

Answer (score 2):

Some points to add to what have already been said:

- Comment to help guide improvement of questions and answers.
- Tag questions properly to ease finding content.
- Follow the [tags](https://askubuntu.com/tags) of topics of your expertise to be able easily spot question which you may answer.
- Visit the [meta site](https://meta.askubuntu.com/) to see what the community is up to.
- Rather than trying to do everything you might want to focus on particular tasks and areas to avoid burn out.